# Speed of energy in a pulse wave

Tags: energy, waves, speed

Consider a Dirac pulse giving rise to a wave propagating in a uniform generic medium.

Since all mediums are dispersive and lossy except for vacuum, the frequency components of the pulse will travel at different speeds and will be dampened in different ways.

Therefore, the pulse will be distorted. In particular, it will spread from being a sharp Dirac singularity to a wide envelope distributed in space and time.

However, a receiver at some distance $d_0$, capable of capturing the incoming pulse (e.g. an antenna), will record a clear peak in the absorbed power at some very well defined time instant $t_0$.

We know that phase velocity $v_p=\frac{d\omega}{dk}$ and group velocity $v_g=\frac{\omega}{k}$ are meaningless to calculate this time of arrival (i.e. $t_0\neq\frac{d_0}{v_p}$ and $t_0\neq\frac{d_0}{ v_g}$, in general), as they do not really relate to the speed of energy (light, pressure, etc.) in the medium.

Thus, my question: is there a way to determine $t_0$, assuming the dispersion spectrum of the medium is known?

In other words: is there a way to compute a "speed of energy ($v_e$)" defined as the speed at which a power peak travels in a uniform generic medium?